# Does spring container create new beans for the objects which belong to same generic class but use different types?

Tags: java, spring, generics, inversion-of-control

If i autowire my generic class with different types in different controllers, does spring container create new instance for each?

Assume i have a generic class.

```
@Component
class MyClass<T, K>{

    public K doStuff(T t){
        // some logic here
    }

}
```

In a controller i use

```
@Autowired
MyClass<Employee, Integer> myClass;
```

and in another controller i use

```
@Autowired
MyClass<Manager, String> myClass;
```

Comment: Did you try this out? (As a side note, don't use field injection, as it has lots of problems. Use constructor injection instead.)

Comment: Introduction of a basic feature update, old but still the most common case: https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/03/spring-framework-4-0-and-java-generics

Comment: @Deadpool I think this is not a duplicate of the question you have linked. We can use `@Bean` annotation to create generic types of beans inside configuration classes. But @Lettibe is trying something different. He is trying to annotate a Generic class and make a bean out of it. I have never tried something like that, and doubtful if that is possible. Someone can experiment with it and publish the result for us to enlighten.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made a test for it using Spring `5.1.6-RELEASE` . Here is the code and output :

```
@Component
public class TestClassWithInteger {

    private MyClass<Integer, Integer> myClass;

    @Autowired
    public TestClassWithInteger(MyClass<Integer, Integer> myClass) {
        this.myClass = myClass;

        this.perform();
    }


    public void perform() {
        System.out.println(myClass);
        myClass.doStuff(1);
    }
}

@Component
public class TestClassWithString {

    private MyClass<String, String> myClass;

    @Autowired
    public TestClassWithString(MyClass<String, String> myClass) {
        this.myClass = myClass;

        this.perform();
    }


    public void perform() {
        System.out.println(myClass);
        myClass.doStuff("test");
    }
}

@Component
class MyClass<T, K>{

    public K doStuff(T t){
        System.out.println(t);
        return null;
    }

}
```

The output is :

```
test.example.MyClass@841e575
1
test.example.MyClass@841e575
test
```

So as you can see, because of the fact that your generic bean is a singleton by default, it is returned by the application context - notice the hex of hashcode when printing the object - it is the same. When we change `MyClass` bean scope to prototype then the output is :

```
test.example.MyClass@533b266e
1
test.example.MyClass@62679465
test
```

you get new instance whenever application context is queried for a new bean - as expected.

So the answer for the question :

> Does spring container create new beans for the objects which belong to same generic class but use different types?

is : **No, it does not**.

And to shed some light on how it works we can refer to Phillip Webb's comment posted [here](https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/03/spring-framework-4-0-and-java-generics) :

> Although erasure happens at the object level, there's a lot of information still in the bytecode. By starting at a `field`, `parameter` or `return` type we can inspect the information that's still there. For example, if you look at `java.lang.reflect.Method` you'll see that in addition to `getReturnType` that is a `getGenericReturnType` method which provides a lot more information. Spring's `ResolvableType` just tries to make this information easier to access.